# c_type python add values

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to add some values to an existing variable. I am kind of new to Python. I am using ctype variables. This is my code which doesn't work.

```
rgdSamples = (c_double * 100)()
fSamples = (c_double * 1000)()
for i in range(10)
   fSamples += rgdSamples;
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to actually do? Why do you need ctypes?

Comment: The main project is something that I can't post. This is an example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please at least post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You declared 2 arrays, and you try to add them, which makes no sense. How would you like *fSamples* to look like? Is it a (2D) matrix?

Answer (score -1):

Based on the numeric values from your snippet, I assumed that *fSamples* should be a *2D* array (*10* rows, *100* columns) of *double*s. 
Not clear why [[Python 3]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) is preferred instead of *Python* lists, but here's an example (for display purposes, arrays are much smaller).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes


COLS = 10  # Change it to 100
ROWS = 5  # change it to 10
DoubleArr1D = ctypes.c_double * COLS
DoubleArr2D = (ctypes.c_double * COLS) * ROWS  # Parentheses present for clarity only


def print_matrix(matrix, text=None):  # This function isn't very Pythonic, but keeping it like this for clarity
    if text is not None:
        print(text)
    for row in matrix:
        for element in row:
            print("{:6.2f}  ".format(element), end="")
        print()
    print()


def main():
    mat = DoubleArr2D()  # Initialize matrix with 0s
    arr = DoubleArr1D(*range(1, COLS + 1))  # Initialize array with numbers 1..COLS
    print_matrix(mat, text="Initial matrix:")

    for row_idx in range(ROWS):
        for col_idx in range(COLS):
            mat[row_idx][col_idx] += arr[col_idx] * (row_idx + 1)  # Add the values from array (multiplied by a factor) to the current row

    print_matrix(mat, text="Final matrix:")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("Done.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q055494830]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Initial matrix:
>   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
>   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
>   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
>   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
>   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
>
> Final matrix:
>   1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00   10.00
>   2.00    4.00    6.00    8.00   10.00   12.00   14.00   16.00   18.00   20.00
>   3.00    6.00    9.00   12.00   15.00   18.00   21.00   24.00   27.00   30.00
>   4.00    8.00   12.00   16.00   20.00   24.00   28.00   32.00   36.00   40.00
>   5.00   10.00   15.00   20.00   25.00   30.00   35.00   40.00   45.00   50.00
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: @kostas: Is this what you're after? Or it's totally wrong?